# Line object not selectable after creation

Tags: fabricjs

I have set up a small [**plunkr**](http://jsfiddle.net/URWru/2841/) demonstrating what problem I am working on. After a line is created in drawing mode, it is not able to be selected with 'point-click' after exiting drawing mode, only 'group-selection'. I want objects (not just lines) to be unselectable during drawing, then selectable afterwards. I have tried to create all lines with `selectable: false` then after exiting drawing mode,

```
canvas.forEachObject(function(o){
   o.selectable=true; 
   canvas.renderAll()
})
```

but that does not work either. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use setCoords() function in order to select line.
Update you mouse:up event like this:

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
  isDown = false;
  line.setCoords();
});
```

Please see [when to use setCoords()](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/When-to-call-setCoords).